# Почему append добавляет элемент ко всем спискам в списке [[], [], []]?

Tags: python, списки

x = [[]]*3, получаем [[], [], []]. Почему, если написать x[0].append('a'), мы получаем: [[a], [a], [a]], а не [[a], [], []]?

Comment: У!

     x=[[]]*3
     x[0] is x[1] --- True
     y = list(map(lambda a: a[:], x)
     y[0].append('a')
     y --- [['a'], [], []]

Comment: нет, вопрос был почему так происходит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему так происходит: потому что при умножении питон копирует каждое значение по ссылке, и по факту все три списка ссылаются на один объект в памяти. Эта проблема сохранится для всех изменяемых (mutable) типов (просто потому что неизменяемые для сохранения изменений необходимо перезаписывать).

Хороших комментариев я по этому поводу не нашел, кроме вот этого:

> But there is a caveat. When building a new list by multiplying, Python copies each item by reference. This poses a problem for mutable items, for instance in a multidimensional array where each element is itself a list.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Lists

Ну и на всякий: самый простой способ скопировать список, а не ссылку на него - это slice без ограничений

```
b = a[:]
```

Comment: это я знаю, просто стало интересно, почему в этом случае так происходит. спасибо за ответ)